# Flash the changes after loading edits without refreshing

Tags: feature-request, edits, design

Whenever there's an edit made to a post and this message appears to update the view

```
                    an edit has been made to this post; click to load
```

Then when you click it and the view is updated, it is not clear exactly what was changed in the post when the new post is flashed.

If the flash would actually highlight the changes (like it does in the edit history) that would be super.

So instead of updating the view plainly, it could be made to flash the post (like when you visit a link of an answer and it scrolls and flashes it), with the changes highlighted

So for example the updated view could appear like this for ~0.5 secs:

> Question Title
>   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, `this was added in the post` when an unknown printer took a galley of type and <strike>`this was removed`</strike> a type specimen book.

and then back to normal view

Question Title
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, this was added in the post when an unknown printer took a galley of type and a type specimen book.

Comment: Permanently until reloading the page? Or maybe on a timer (e.g., 30 secs)?

Comment: @NickStauner Just for the duration of the flash (0.5 sec?) would do I guess. Once the eye has noticed where the changes are it sort of imprints in anyways..